# How can I have my buttons stay inline side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have been attempting to align two buttons in a div side by side. I have tried some of the advice I have seen on StackOverflow, and believe this is a specific issue to the way I have formated, below is the code. Thank you for your help.

```css
.beegButtons {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #D73F09;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.beegButtons:hover,
.beegButtons:focus {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#buttonBox {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#buttonDiv {
  background-color: #D73F09;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonDiv">
  <div id="buttonBox">
    <p class="fas fa-cloud">
      <button class="beegButtons" type="button">&nbsp;Meeting Minutes</button></p>

    <p class="fas fa-cloud">
      <button class="beegButtons" type="button">&nbsp;Presentation Slides</button></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Image for refference to the current state:
[image]

Comment: reset display for your <p> or wrap the button inside a span instead.

Comment: `p {display: inline-block;}` ???

Answer (score 2):

you can add this css;

```
#buttonBox p{
    float:left;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by:

```css
#buttonBox {  display: flex;  flex-wrap: wrap;  align-content: stretch;}
```

Or even:

```
p {display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: Yep, and I would even go so far to remove the `p` tag because it's not doing anything, and it's the wrong semantics anyways.

Comment: @RickardElimää agree, but lately i feel that changing too much of OPs original code it's not ligit so i try to fix the one that been asked  (: